# How do I serve Rails development environment assets over local network?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost, asset-pipeline, development-environment

I have a Rails 5 application I am running in development mode (`RAILS_ENV=development`). The Rails server was started with `bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3002`. Computers on the same network (subnet) as me can access my Rails application by IP in a browser, e.g. `http://10.123.10.5:3002/`. However, links to assets such as images are broken.

If I inspect the image in a browser, the tag will reference localhost as the host part of the IP such as `<img src="http://localhost:3001/assets/logo-70eb2453cbce2a1790196aeb4ff1db9cddd3789b951bed9a6815505a490318a6.png">`.

If I change the src to use the correct subnet IP, it works as expected. E.g. `<img src="http://10.123.10.5:3002/assets/logo-70eb2453cbce2a1790196aeb4ff1db9cddd3789b951bed9a6815505a490318a6.png">`

Note, also, that even the port seems to be incorrect, not adhering to the port specified in the `rails s` command

How do I remedy this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the `config.asset_host` in you rails application with your IP address